# How dangerous is it not to load `seccomp` rules for LXC containers?

Tags: security, lxc, container, stability

## Context

In my "quest" to [get LXC to run on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53884/why-dont-lxc-containers-start-on-rpi1b-lxc-seccomp-policy-loading-error) I may be forced to disable loading the [seccomp](https://code.google.com/archive/p/seccompsandbox/wikis/overview.wiki) configuration at container startup, by commenting it out in `/usr/share/lxc/config/debian.common.conf`:

```
# Blacklist some syscalls which are not safe in privileged
# containers
#  lxc.seccomp = /usr/share/lxc/config/common.seccomp
```

As (a.t.m.) only *than* the container starts (otherwise an error is raised)..

Turning off such a basic security setting that is so heavily tied to containerization/sandboxing is, to some extend, defeating the purpose of LXC. From a security/stability point of view I would very much like to keep blacklisting most of the system calls when running the LXC containers (as configured by LXC defaults in `/usr/share/lxc/config/common.seccomp`):

```
2
blacklist
[all]
kexec_load errno 1
open_by_handle_at errno 1
init_module errno 1
finit_module errno 1
delete_module errno 1
```

## Questions

Does not 'loading seccomp rules for LXC containers' yield:

1. *significant* * security issues?
2. any other *technical* (application or stability) issues?

*Assuming I am the only one using the "mother" system and its LXC containers (otherwise it would be evident..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the seccomp rules prevent a container from modifying the host kernel. Without them, UID 0 in a container can use kexec(if that even works on Raspbian, I'm not sure) to load a new kernel(apparently not to start it) and `insmod`/`rmmod` to load/unload modules among other things as these syscalls don't take user namespaces into account correctly.

Whether this is a significant security issue is up to you - you just need to keep in mind that now UID 0 in the container can effectively become UID 0 outside of the container, i.e. it's possible for root to escape the container by loading a crafted module for example.

Comment: Thanks for your insights @maxf ! Is a "jail escape" by UID0 indeed the *only* thing to keep in mind? In that case, acknowledging (assuming?) I will be the only one having access to the system, this would not pose an issue for me.

Any other (security / technical stability) risks I should think about?

Comment: Well, you could also crash the host by `rmmod --force` something important. But generally, as far as I know how LXC works, that's about it. If you're the only user and you don't use LXC to provide isolation, then you're _probably fine_ (tm).

Comment: @woosting Generally, a jail escape is the worst thing that can happen with a container. So if that doesn't worry you then go ahead!